# cmake - NMake Makefiles issue

Tags: c, cmake

I have a source code tree as follows

```
daily_build
  ->src_dir1
  ->src_dir2
   ..
```

We have been using cmake-gui to configure and generate for Visual Studio 8 2005.
However, on a separate machine, we are trying to automate the build process for nightly builds.

In order to this we are trying to run cmake from command line as follows

```
1) vcvars32.bat 
2) svn co <url path> D:\daily_build
3) cd daily_build\build\gen\host
4) cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" D:\daily_build
```

However, CMake exits with error

```
CMake Error :CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "NMake Makefiles"......
```

However, in the very same prompt, I can run cl.exe and nmake.

Further, If I look in the CMakeFiles folder, there is no error.log. All I can see is CMakeOutput.txt and the ouput file shows that CMakeCCompilerId.exe and CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe were both generated successfully.

Does anyone have any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run CMake in verbose mode and see where it fails.

Comment: @rubenvb : is their a verbose switch to cmake? do you mean --debug-output

Comment: @rubenvb : I tried debug-output and i think I know why cmake is failing. In my source tree, cmakeLists, we have mentioned set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM devenv). If i comment this line, cmake works. I thought devenv is the correct setting here?

Comment: No. That shouldn't be set in the CMakeLists.txt file at all; it is set by the generator used (as you've seen first hand).